# Why some additional parameter like HTTP/1.1,iHTTP/1.1.. added in a data URL

Tags: c#, api, http, firewall

I have notice a case that some time some data request include some additional parameter like HTTP/1.1,iHTTP/1.1.... i don't know why this happen. If anybody have any idea about this..?
 this is my original request

```
 /list?_dc=1416421960540&name=w&page=1&start=0&limit=12&sort=LastName&dir=DESC
```

but sometime it include some another parameter like

```
 /list?_dc=1416421960540&name=w&page=1&start=0&limit=12&sort=LastName&dir=DESCiHTTP/1.1
 /List?_dc=1416421960830&name=wol&page=1&start=0&limit=12&sort=LastName&dir=DESCTTP/1.1
 /List?_dc=1416421951395&page=1&start=0&limit=12&sort=LastName&dir=ASCtHTTP/1.1
```

If any idea, please let me know.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

This looks like whatever you're viewing the request with is cutting off the "GET" part of the URL. Most likely, the "HTTP/1.1" is not part of the actual URL being visited.

HTTP/1.1 is part of the request header. A normal header starts with:

`GET /list?_dc... HTTP/1.1
HOST: mydomain.com`

It's also possible that the request is getting corrupted due to a small buffer size for the URL or something of that nature.

What are you generating these requests with? which libraries?

Comment: I am using EXTJS library for creating the request URL. This is  working fine in most of the case. but the above situation occur 4 times. Is there any way to avoid that..?